# Package.json pasting a package name in bad?

Tags: npm

What happens differently when you go into your package.json and paste a package name in and do `npm i` vs. doing it the real `npm i package-name`?

package.json:

```
"dep": 1.0.0
```

vs

```
npm i dep --save
```

We have a build error and learned can bypass it by pasting. I know it isn't kosher but I really want to know why and what consequences that causes?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install dep` doesn't add the dependency to the `package.json` file.

You have to add `--save` or `--save-dev` to add it to the `package.json` file.

Besides that, `npm install` will always serve you the latest build (in most cases the version tagged as latest (see [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install))), unless you specify a specific version.

If you want your lock file to update, you have to delete the file before running `npm install` to generate a lock file with the dependency included (for more info check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866))

In conclussion it shouldn't make much of a difference if you manually add the dependency to `package.json` file and install it with `npm install`, unless the latest version of your dependency is broken.

Comment: but package-lock.json isn't regenerated until you do `npm i pkg-name --save` so what other downside exists.